# Dictionary won't update with a string as key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to update a dictionary using a function returning a tuple where the first element is a string.

```
>>> def t():
...     return 'ABC', 123
```

However the [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#dict.update) function does not quite like it.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(t())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

I can also try dictionary comprehension and get the same unexpected result.

```
>>> d.update({k: v for k, v in t()})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The only working way is to first save returned value.

```
>>> x = t()
>>> d.update({x[0]: x[1]})
>>> d
{'ABC': 123}
```

How to explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#dict.update)

> `update()` accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs: `d.update(red=1, blue=2)`.

For example:

```
In [1]: d = {}

In [2]: def t(): return [('ABC', '123')]

In [3]: d.update(t())

In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'ABC': '123'}

In [5]: d2 = {}

In [6]: def t2(): return {'ABC': '123'}

In [7]: d2.update(t2())

In [8]: d2
Out[8]: {'ABC': '123'}
```

Comment: My misunderstanding was coming from the fact that an iterable of length two (i.e `(a, b)`) would make it. While in fact the `update` function expects an iterable of iterables of length two (i.e `[(a, b)]`).

Answer (score 1):

@Jack's answer is the one.

In both your failed examples, you're using **a pair** instead of **a sequence of pairs**.

Also, just to add some sauce, here are two more ways to do it:

```
def t():
    return 'ABC', 123
d = {}
d.update([ t() ])
d
=> {'ABC': 123}
d = {}
d.__setitem__(*t())
d
=> {'ABC': 123}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more simply, change `t()` to return a `{key: value}` as such:

```
def t():
    return {'ABC': 123}
```

Should do the trick for you.